# C# Can't get MessageBox to display Variables

Tags: c#, variables, messagebox

It's displaying my result just fine, but I would like to add the following dialogue "A box with length l, width w, and height h, has a volume of x." (l, w, h, and x being the user's input.

```
 double heightLabelBox;
 double lengthLabelBox;
 double widthLabelBox;
 double result;

        heightLabelBox = double.Parse(heightTextBox.Text);

        lengthLabelBox = double.Parse(lengthTextBox.Text);

        widthLabelBox = double.Parse(lengthTextBox.Text);

        result = heightLabelBox * lengthLabelBox * widthLabelBox;

 MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

Comment: why don't you join the string together along with the result.ToString()? What have you tried?

Comment: google string concatenation in c#

Comment: Please do not forget to add checks to see if the values from the textboxes are in fact valid doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 MessageBox.Show(string.format("A box with length {0}, width {1} and height {2} has a volume of {3}", lengthLabelBox, widthLabelBox, heightLabelBox, result));
```

however there is no point in trying to format it in this manner since you already have the textbox values therefore just concatenate it using either string.Join or the "+" operator to join the strings together, or use string.Format about and just take the textbox values instead and place it instead of the parsed values.

you can also use the StringBuilder:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(50); // give it an initial value/capacity.
sb.AppendFormat("A box with length {0}, width {1} and height {2} has a volume of {3}", lengthTextBox.Text, widthTextBox.Text, heightTextBox.Text, result);

MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the output from your messagebox.show? Try converting the double variables to strings first / or and use a string.Format to create a new variable, or in the messagebox declaration itself. You might also want to shorten the double values to fewer decimal place.